# adding pages in underscores.me theme

Tags: menus, themes, pages

I have a basic question. I am fairly new to WordPress and I have this task that I am asked to do.

I have been asked to add pages (contact, about, portfolio, etc...) to the current WordPress site that was created using the Underscores.me theme. Now my question is, can I simply access the back-end of the site and add pages from the WordPress menu or would I have to code out the page? and then assign it to a Menu?

Like let's assume I am given the back-end access, can I simply click "add pages" -> add content -> "assign it menu" -> publish?

Is that possible if the current theme was created using underscore? or Do I have to know detailed coding to achieve the task of adding a page?

Comment: Yes, that should probably just work. Even if there's no page template already it should use the default one fine, and it looks like underscores does provide a menu. So unless someone's done something crazy to the theme you should be fine. I guess you don't already have access to the site or the theme so you can't just try it?

Comment: Yes I don't have the access to the backend and the current menu is all over the place and doesn't have any of the basic "nav options" like about, contact, ... So I just wanted to know when I am done creating those pages, I would just use the dashboard and assign it to a menu.

Comment: Once the page is made you would go to 'Appearance > Menus' choose the menu you want to modify and there's a simple checklist of pages that you can look through to just add them.  Then it's drag and drop from there.